# a short theorem about poles

Tags: complex-analysis

The theorem: If $f$ has a pole at $z_0$ then there exists a $\delta > 0 $ and a nonvanishing holomorphic function $h(z)$ on the disc $D(z_0, \delta)$ and $\exists$ a unique positive integer $N$ s.t. $f(z) = (z-z_0)^{-N}h(z) $$\forall z \in D(z_0, \delta)$

The proof is as follows:

$1/f$ has a zero at $z_0$ by defn, so $(1/f)(z) = (z-z_0)^Ng(z) $with $g(z) \not = 0$ on $D(z,\delta)$ This is from a previous theorem.

However, the previous theorem states that the function $1/f$ has to be 1. Holomorphic on $D(z_0,\delta)$ and 2. has to not be identically 0. How do we know both of these conditions hold in order to state the form of $(1/f)(z)$?

Comment: What’s your definition of a pole?

Comment: Did you mean to put, *"...$\exists$ a unique positive integer $N$ s.t. $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{-N}h(z),\,\,\forall z \in D(z_0,\delta)$"*?

Comment: @k.stm if $z_0$ is an isolated singularity of $f(z)$ and $1/f: D(z_0,r) \to \mathbb{C}$ has a zero at $z_0$ we say $z_0$ is a pole of $f(z)$

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Yes thank you, I will edit it

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is holomorphic on the punctured disk $D(z_0,\delta)\setminus\{z_0\}$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Yes looking at the definition from k.stm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ has an *isolated* singularity at $z_0$, by your definiton it’s holomorphic on some punctured disk $D(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ where, by your definition of poles, $f$ also doesn’t assume any zeros.¹

You may state this as $f(D(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}) ⊂ ℂ^×$.

Thus, $1/f$ is defined on $D(z_0,r)$ and holomorphic as a composition of holomorphic functions $1/f = 1/z ∘ f$ (where $1/z \colon ℂ^× → ℂ^×,~z ↦ 1/z$). On this *punctured disk* $f$ doesn’t even assume zero once, so it certainly isn’t identically zero.

---

¹: Note that with your definition of pole, you implicitly assume that a punctured disks exist on which $f$ has no zeros, else $1/f$ wouldn’t be defined. Without loss of generality, you may assume $D(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ is such a punctured disk.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. You stated that "... It doesn't even assume zero once, so it certainly isn't identically zero." But, $(1/f)(z_0) = 0$ by definition, so why can't I assume it is zero everywhere else?

Comment: @james1395 It doesn’t assume any zeroes on some *punctured* disk $D(z_0,r)\setminus\{z_0\}$ because this is a disk (given by the definition of an *isolated* singularity) on which $f$ was holomorphic in the *usual* sense.

Comment: I agree that $f$ doesn't assume any zeroes on the punctured disc you described, but I'm finding it hard to translate that to $1/f$ having no zeroes on the disc (not punctured) $D(z_0,r)$

Comment: @james1395 No, I meant: $f$ assumes only nonzero complex values $f(z) ∈ ℂ^×$ for $z$ in the punctured disk, because the disk is chosen such that the singularity $z_0$ is the only one in it (which is possible because it’s an isolated singularity). But for $f(z) ∈ ℂ^×$, $1/f(z) ∈ ℂ^×$, so in particular $1/f(z) ≠ 0$. (No invertible element can be zero.)

Comment: @james1395 Another way of looking at it. If $1/f$ were identically zero, what would that means about $f$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski Would it OK saying that that would mean $f$ is then undefined $\forall z$ (and therefore not holomorphic)?

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: @k.stm I'm still not really following. You say that $f$ assumes only nonzero complex values for z in the punctured disc, let's start here - why is this?

Comment: @james1395 (1) There’s a punctured disk around $z_0$ on which $f$ doesn’t assume $∞$, because $z_0$ is an *isolated* singularity. (2) here’s a punctured disk around $z_0$ on which $f$ doesn’t assume $0$, because $z_0$ is a pole. (3) Intersect both punctured disks to get one for which both (1) and (2) hold. (Also note that your definition of pole isn’t clear about (2) – it states that *implicitly* – see the footnote in my answer.)

Comment: @k.stm I Agree with (1), however for (2) I do not understand what you mean. Why does $z_0$ being a pole mean $f$ doesn't assume to be $0$ for some punctured disc?

Comment: @james1395 Have you read the footnote? I don’t know what else to say, it’s all in there. You’re working with a bad definition of pole. Unless you ask more concrete questions, I won’t reply anymore.

Comment: @k.stm Yes I've read it, I just don't see how it would implicitly imply that $f$ has no zeroes in the punctured disc. This is the definition my lecturer gave us of a pole. Do you have a definition that would make this easier to understand?

Comment: @james1395 What does it mean for a function to be holomorphic? What functions are called holomorphic? Maybe you should revisit this definition and then think about what this (implicitly) implies for $1/f$ in your definition of pole.